# Unable to create Service Reference in VS 2015

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-web-api, odata, service-reference

I've created Asp.Net Web API 2 OData 3 data source. Request to `http://localhost:3000/odata/$metadata` produces EDMX scheme:

```
<edmx:Edmx xmlns:edmx="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/06/edmx" Version="1.0">
<edmx:DataServices xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata" m:DataServiceVersion="3.0" m:MaxDataServiceVersion="3.0">
<Schema xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/edm" Namespace="mPOS.API.Controllers">
<EntityType Name="Book">
<Key>
<PropertyRef Name="Id"/>
</Key>
<Property Name="Id" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="false"/>
<Property Name="Title" Type="Edm.String"/>
<Property Name="Count" Type="Edm.Int32"/>
<Property Name="Price" Type="System.Nullable_1OfMoney"/>
</EntityType>
</Schema>
<Schema xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/edm" Namespace="System">
<ComplexType Name="Nullable_1OfMoney"/>
</Schema>
<Schema xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/edm" Namespace="Default">
<EntityContainer Name="Container" m:IsDefaultEntityContainer="true">
<EntitySet Name="Books" EntityType="mPOS.API.Controllers.Book"/>
</EntityContainer>
</Schema>
</edmx:DataServices>
</edmx:Edmx>
```

When I try to create Service Reference in Client project, I got an error:

**0141: The namespace 'System' is a system namespace and cannot be used by other schemas. Choose another namespace name**

So the problematic part in produced EDMX scheme is property *Price* thats type *System.Nullable_1OfMoney* is specified as *Complex Type* in schema defined in *System* namespace.

How could I create this Service Reference? I'm using VS 2015 Community Edition.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that service references can only be created for OData service up to version 3.